# Local dev version brome

Tags: database

I had some issues with my local dev version of my Magento 1 website so I copied all the files from the live site to my local and broke it :-/

I'm now getting database access errors as below:
Can anyone help out please?
'myusername' is in place of my real username
'mywebsite' is in place of my real website name

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myusername'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
 1. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
 2.  C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
 3. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
 4. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
\xampp\htdocs\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
 5. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
 6. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
 7. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
 8. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
 9. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
 10. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
 11. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
 12. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
 13. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1202): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
 14. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
 15. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(297): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
 16. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
 17. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
 18. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
 19. C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(90): Mage::run('mywebsite', 'website')
 20. {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to export your database from live site and import to your local machine server.
Then go to **app/etc/local.xml** file and update below code as per your local machine's Database details.

```
<connection>
    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host> <!-- YOUR DB HOSTNAME -->
    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username> <!-- YOUR DB USERNAME -->
    <password><![CDATA[]]></password> <!-- YOUR DB PASSWORD, LEAVE BLANK IF NO PASSWORD REQUIRED -->
    <dbname><![CDATA[magento1800]]></dbname> <!-- YOUR DB NAME -->
    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
    <active>1</active>
</connection>
```

Once done, Go to phpmyadmin, Open your database and modify `core_config_data` table, Update rows where path value

> web/unsecure/base_url set to http://YOUR_SITE_LOCAL_URL/
>
> web/secure/base_url set to https://YOUR_SITE_LOCAL_URL/

Clear `var/cache` and `var/session` folders.

Comment: If it helped, just mark this answer as correct by clicking on tick mark beside the answer so it may help others find the correct solution if they are facing similar issue.